# chat.stackexchange not showing graphics

Tags: support, chat

### 2012-12-03: Update:

The problem below seems to be Mac related, and not connectivity related. On my PC the chat appears ok. So what do I need to reset on the Mac to get this corrected?

---

Anyone else having problems with the TeX.SE chat?  Yesterday it started slowing down and since then I don't seem to see the graphics.  Not sure what I need to do to resolve this. I tried restarting Firefox and that did not change anything. There are no problems accessing the main site, or any other sites -- problem is just with chat..

Here is what it look like for me.

[image]

Comment: I can’t help. Here (in Germany) it works fine, now. But you should know that StackExchange has serious problems due to Hurrican Sandy, cf. the answer to my question [What happened to stack2rss.stackexchange.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153229/what-happened-to-stack2rss-stackexchange-com) (and follow the links in it).

Comment: @Speravir: Yeah they are based in New York, so perhaps the chat servers are there. But it seems that others are not seeing this problem. I have been seeing this all day -- just checked and same behavior.  I don't think the amount of traffic on chat would be high enough to warrant having multiple servers, so not sure why I am the only one experiencing this problem.

Comment: They seem to have moved chat.stackexchange.com to Oregon in time or it was originally there _(because on Monday, when all other sites were in read-only-mode, chatting was possible, at least no message appeared)_. But the line from your location may be bad now, and it does not need to be related to the Hurrican issue.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but have you tried `Ctrl+F5` ?

Comment: @tohecz: That just enabled voice over. Still can't access chat on Mac!!

Comment: On Mac? Try to find "clear cache" (I don't know the keyboard shortcut).

Comment: @tohecz: Thank You. That did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find "clear cache" (I don't know the keyboard shortcut).